# $location does not navigate on first ng-click callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

Something weird is going on in my AngularJS application. I have a view which has a list of anchor tags bound to an array of objects (I'm using `ng-repeat` to render the list). Each one of the anchor tag has an `ng-click` bound to a method on the controller. The method is as follows:

```
    $scope.onSiteSelected = function ($event, site) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Site/GetSiteMap/' + site.Id,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response && response.length > 0) {
                    menuManager.setSiteMap($scope.$root.menu, response[0]);
                    var url = response[0].Children[0].Settings.Url;
                    $location.path(url);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The `url` var is being initialized to the correct value every time. But, when I click on the anchor tag the first time, `$location.path(url)` does nothing, and when I click it for a second time, it does navigate to the target url.

**UPDATE:**

Ok I got it working by using the `$http` service as follows:

```
    $scope.onSiteSelected = function ($event, site) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        var address = '/Site/GetSiteMap/' + site.Id;
        $http.get(address)
            .success(function (response) {
                if (response && response.length > 0) {
                    menuManager.setSiteMap($scope.$root.menu, response[0]);
                    var url = response[0].Children[2].Settings.Url;
                    $location.path(url);
                }
            });
    }
```

Does it really make a difference if I used `$,ajax` or `$http`? I thought the two can be used interchangeably...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot use them interchangibly, `$.ajax`  is `jQuery` whereas `$http` is angular's http service.

Resist the urge to use jQuery as there is almost always a way to do it in the angular way.

That being said, if you do something outside of angular world, (mostly callbacks didn't occur from angular), you need to apply the changes to force a `digest` cycle.

```
$.doSth(function callback() {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        // your actual code
    });
});
```

Please read the most voted answer in ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) . This would guide you to avoid using jQuery where there is an alternative.

Comment: Ah I see. The thing is, this is my first AngularJS project, and my team mate has already worked on a project which used AngularJS. She had all sorts of trouble trying to do cross-origin requests using the `$http` service. Eventually, she had to do all her AJAX requests outside the context of AngularJS. Do you know whether `$http` has built-in support for CORS requests?